# I got kernel compiling error but i cant google it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, kernel, system

```
root@com:/usr/src/linux-source-4.15.0/linux-source-4.15.0# make -C $KERN_DIR M=`pwd` modules

echo $KERN_DIR -> /usr/src/linux-source-4.15.0/linux-source-4.15.0
```

how can i fix it? i cant find this error

```
drivers/tty/serdev/core.o: failed
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target 'drivers/tty/serdev/core.o' failed
make[3]: *** [drivers/tty/serdev/core.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:604: recipe for target 'drivers/tty/serdev' failed
make[2]: *** [drivers/tty/derdev] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:604: recipe for target 'drivers/tty' failed
make[1]: *** [drivers/tty] Error 2
Makefile:1060: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

Comment: May be more appropriate at https://unix.stackexchange.com but please read their help guidlines for on-topic questions.  Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: The actual error message, which could help in understanding the problem, is somewhere above the line `drivers/tty/serdev/core.o: failed`.